# Getting Column Names of a Table Ado.NET

Tags: datatable, ado.net

I'm trying to get column names of a table, but it only returns the column names such as `TABLE_SCHEMA`,`TABLE_NAME`,`TABLE_CATALOG`,`TABLE_TYPE`.
Here's the code;

```
DataTable table = con.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, "Contact" });
var columnNames = (from DataRow r in table.Rows
                               from DataColumn c in table.Columns
                               select c.ColumnName).ToList();
```

I need to save the names in a list.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DataTable table = con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { null, null, "Contact" });
```

you have to specify Columns instead of Tables as collectionName ...

you should also change your linq query to something like this:

```
var columnNames = (from r in tab.AsEnumerable() 
                        select r.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME")).ToList();
```